# why does the domain name get delete during setup using a Cloudinit script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, sssd, cloud-init

I am using a Cloud-Init script to setup up my Ubuntu 22.04 server.

but when i check the logs to join an active directory it delete the subdomain name why?

i can only remote connect through IP address but not by the hosts name or the subdomain name that the machine is register with?

I also include the script in

```yaml
hostname: "testmachine"  # <-- 
fqdn: "testmachine.mrsomething.mr" # <--

write_files:
  
  - path: /home/root/01-netcfg.yaml
    content: |
      network:
        version: 2
        ethernets:
          ens3:
            addresses:
              - 10.1.44.181/24  <-- IP Address of the machine
            nameservers:
              addresses:
                - 10.1.44.11   <-- Domain name controller 1
                - 10.1.44.12   <-- Domain name controller 2
              search:
                - "mrsomething.mr"
                - "mr"
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: 10.1.44.1
            mtu: 3000
    owner: root:root

  - path: /home/root/krb5.conf
    content: |
      [logging]
        default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
        kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
        admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
      
      [libdefaults]
        default_realm = MRSOMETHING.MR
        dns_lookup_realm = true
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
        ticket_lifetime = 24h
        renew_lifetime = 7d
        forwardable = true
        rdns = true
      
      [realms]
      MRSOMETHING.MR = {
          kdc = dc1.mrsomething.mr
          kdc = dc2.mrsomething.mr
          admin_server = dc1.mrsomething.mr
          default_domain = mrsomething.mr
          primary_kdc = dc1.mrsomething.mr
      }
      
      [domain_realm]
        .mrsomething.mr = MRSOMETHING.MR
        mrsomething.mr = MRSOMETHING.MR
    owner: root:root

  - path: /home/root/sssd.conf
    content: |
      [sssd]
      domains = mrsomething.mr, testmachine.mrsomething.mr, magic.mrsomething.mr
      config_file_version = 2
      services = nss, pam
      default_domain_suffix = MRSOMETHING.MR
      
      [domain/mrsomething.mr]
      ad_domain = mrsomething.mr 
      krb5_realm = MRSOMETHING.MR
      realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
      default_shell = /bin/bash
      krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
      cache_credentials = True
      id_provider = ad
      override_homedir = /home/%u
      fallback_homedir = /home/%u
      ldap_id_mapping = True
      access_provider = simple
      simple_allow_groups = domain admins
      use_fully_qualified_names = True

runcmd:
 
 - "rm /etc/netplan/*"
 - "mv /home/root/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml"
 - "netplan apply"

 # download docker ....

 # Update all installed packages.
 
 # join realm

 - "echo 'password123' | realm join mrsomething.mr --user=mrjoiner"   

 - "mv /home/root/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf"
 - "mv /home/root/sssd.conf /etc/sssd/sssd.conf"
 - "chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf"

  # Make sure our users get a home directory
  - "pam-auth-update --enable mkhomedir"

  - "systemctl enable sssd"
  - "systemctl start sssd"

 - "reboot"
```

when i check the logs for "sssd_mrsomething.mr.log"

I see this in it.

"update delete testmachine. in A
update add testmachine. 3600 in A 10.1.44.181
send
update delete testmachine. in AAAA"